# Tools to Listen for Database Updates

Tags: database, postgresql, database-connection

I'm extremely new towards databases, so I apologize in advance. I have been tasked with a problem to update tables in one database if another is updated. From what I've read, this is considered bad practice (duplicating data); however, the two programs that use the two databases are too large to make any changes to update tables in both of the respective tables.

As a temporary solution, we are planning on implementing a service that pulls from one database and updates the tables in another. The tables may not have the same identical names, but they will hold the same attributes. At this moment, I believe one database is Oracle and the other is Postgres.

What frameworks / languages / services would be most appropriate to complete this plan of action? We were thinking about using Flask or another API, but were unsure if this is truly needed. Is there an easier solution than building an API?

Comment: How many tables? The answer is likely to be different if its one table vs 1000. Also, what is the latency allowed? Is this a nightly job, hourly, or sub-second sync?

Comment: We’re referring to about 50 - 80 different tables. We expect it to be sub-second sync